# Azure files giving permission denied in kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have configured azure file volume for my pod for an application. when i try to run it, it shows error.

> Warning  FailedMount 0s (x7 over 32s) kubelet,
>   aks-nodepool1-39499429-1  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume
>   "lhapidatasource" : mount failed: exit status 32
>
> ```
> Output: mount error(13): Permission denied
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
> ```

Please help

Comment: Could you please show your pod json file? Have you create k8s secret for Azure files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About mount Azure file share to Azure k8s pod, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707379/mounting-azure-file-storage-in-docker-container-via-kubernetes/44712483#44712483).

Note:

1. Need based64 encoded Azure storage account and key.
2. Write the right file share name to azure.yaml:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have followed exact steps. Even then I am getting that error. Any other thing which causes this problem?

Comment: It seems your secret not correct, does that account and key works for that storage account?

Comment: Secret is correct. Earlier it was giving a different error when secret was not provided properly.

Comment: @AnilKumarP could you please show me your yaml file?

Comment: Yes you were right, there was an error while copy pasting security base 64 key. Thanks a lot for your time